# My apple internal SSD has become extremely slow

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-utility, ssd, performance

I have a 2017 13" MacBook Pro with a Apple 500gb SSD, model APPLE SSD AP0512J.

I have noticed over the last year that my machine has become more and more frustrating to use - everything just loads slowly. I finally ran a Blackmagic Disk Speed Test and I am not getting anything above 1.5 Gb/s, frequently in the 700-800MBps range. Sometimes with read speeds in the 300MBps range.

I downloaded DriveDx - no problems. Ran "First Aid" using disk utility - no issues.

Still getting very slow speeds. The run on the screenshot was done with just a few background programs running (dropbox - not actively doing anything), Magnet, VPN.

Ideas? [image: Disk Speed Test]

Comment: First step is to rule out CPU-bound IO. What does `top` tell you about any tasks taking up more than 20% of the CPU during these slow periods?

Comment: Yes, have a look at Activity Monitor, and see if any processes are using excessive CPU or Memory.

Comment: Repeating Blackmagic test again, I waited for everything to settle after restarting my machine - besides activity monitor (~10%), windowserver was next at 8%.

Read: 882
Write: 960